# Get something out from taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, email, export

I like to use the new taxonomy to make a little CRM, really simple

```
contact
- name
- tel
- email
- company
```

Fine, the secretary will enter all the name in the database of the cms (WordPress), and i will have all those in, able to display it like a list or whatever i like

1) first question, do i reinvent the wheel, is it already done...

Now, with all those nice contact... i have a page, or a list of really good product.. and all those contact can benefit to see it in there mail, much like a newsletter, but simpler...

2) question, how can i get all those email, and have wp to send the wp page/link to those email... plugin, code ?

thanks in advance for the light on that

Comment: You are asking way too much at once here and unlikely to get good complete answers. There are at least three questions here - how to organize data in that structure, how to display it, how to make mailing list out of it... Please consider splitting this in separate more manageable questions.

Comment: The most important part... get taxonomy email in and array to use it...

Comment: name, tel, email, and company are meta data, those should be custom fields associated with a "contact" custom post type. a taxonomy would be "business contacts", "personal contacts", "family" or some other means of categorizing or describing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used http://rolopress.com/ a while back and have nice features for contact administration

Answer (score 0):

**[Start with the Twenty Ten CRM Child Theme](http://www.billerickson.net/twentyten-crm/)**. It's more than a good starting point plus you could everything you mentioned if you code yourself the appropriate widgets/plugins.